# Comparison method violates its general contract! (TimSort)

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, comparison, string-comparison

I apologize, but I have been unable to troubleshoot my issue with running MuTect on my own. I am unsure if there is an issue with my arguments or with one of my inputs or maybe even java itself. I receive this error.

```
   Error processing 1:12855123
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:747)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:483)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:410)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:214)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
    at org.broadinstitute.cga.tools.gatk.walkers.cancer.mutect.MuTectWalker.map(MuTectWalker.java:664)
    at org.broadinstitute.cga.tools.gatk.walkers.cancer.mutect.MuTectWalker.map(MuTectWalker.java:34)
    at org.broadinstitute.sting.gatk.traversals.TraverseLoci.traverse(TraverseLoci.java:77)
    at org.broadinstitute.sting.gatk.traversals.TraverseLoci.traverse(TraverseLoci.java:18)
    at org.broadinstitute.sting.gatk.executive.LinearMicroScheduler.execute(LinearMicroScheduler.java:61)
    at org.broadinstitute.sting.gatk.GenomeAnalysisEngine.execute(GenomeAnalysisEngine.java:225)
    at org.broadinstitute.sting.gatk.CommandLineExecutable.execute(CommandLineExecutable.java:104)
    at org.broadinstitute.sting.commandline.CommandLineProgram.start(CommandLineProgram.java:227)
    at org.broadinstitute.sting.gatk.CommandLineGATK.main(CommandLineGATK.java:89)
```

**My Code:**

```
  Comparator<OfferInfo> comparator = new ComparaterClosesyTOMe();

  public class ComparaterClosesyTOMe implements Comparator<OfferInfo> {
        @Override
        public int compare(OfferInfo arg0, OfferInfo arg1) {

            double distance = Utils.getDistance(gpsTracker.getLatitude(), gpsTracker.getLongitude(), arg0.latitude, arg0.longitude, "M");
            double distance1 = Utils.getDistance(gpsTracker.getLatitude(), gpsTracker.getLongitude(), arg1.latitude, arg1.longitude, "M");

            if (distance > distance1)
                return 1;
           else
               return -1;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you use a custom `Comparator`?

Comment: Yes, I have using Comparator for sort list

Comment: Can you post the code of your comparator please?

Comment: @beeb please check the code

Comment: Try `Double.compare(distance, distance1)` instead of the if else

Answer (score 0):

Use very sample to use and convert your code

**Old Code:**

```
 if (distance > distance1)
     return 1;
 else
     return -1;
```

**New Code:**

```
 if (distance == distance1)
      return 1;
 else   
      return -1;
```